# Reset Logs on runtime in AnyLogic

Tags: logging, reset, anylogic

As I have a production model there is a settling time until the system is filled with agents. Is there any possibility that the standard logs in AnyLogic **logging after settling time or that they are reset at a specific point in time**?

I could delete agents afterwards in Excel, but the analysis of the statistics logs is still falsified then.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such an option. Two options:

1. Either log things into dbase tables yourself (using the `insertInto` command, see the help). Then, you can only start logging after your warmup period.
2. Or keep using automated logging but flag your agents somehow, if they should be excluded, for example by renaming all agents after the warmup period. Then, you can easily filter them out in post-processing